# Why is Vec::len a method instead of a public property?

Tags: methods, rust, visibility, naming

I noticed that Rust's `Vec::len` method just accesses the vector's `len` property. Why isn't `len` just a public property, rather than wrapping a method around it?

I assume this is so that in case the implementation changes in the future, nothing will break because `Vec::len` can change the way it gets the length without any users of `Vec` knowing, but I don't know if there are any other reasons.

The second part of my question is about when I'm designing an API. If I am building my own API, and I have a struct with a `len` property, should I make `len` private and create a public `len()` method? Is it bad practice to make fields public in Rust? I wouldn't think so, but I don't notice this being done often in Rust. For example, I have the following struct:

```
pub struct Segment {
    pub dol_offset: u64,
    pub len: usize,
    pub loading_address: u64,
    pub seg_type: SegmentType,
    pub seg_num: u64,
}
```

Should any of those fields be private and instead have a wrapper function like `Vec` does? If so, then why? Is there a good guideline to follow for this in Rust?

Comment: [One question per post, please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One reason is to provide the same interface for all containers that implement some idea of length. (Such as [`std::iter::ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html#tymethod.len).)

In the case of `Vec`, `len()` is acting like a getter:

```
impl<T> Vec<T> {
    pub fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len
    }
}
```

While this ensures consistency across the standard library, there is another reason underlying this design choice...

This getter protects from external modification of `len`. If the condition `Vec::len <= Vec::buf::cap` is not ever satisfied, `Vec`'s methods may try to access memory illegally. For instance, the implementation of `Vec::push`:

```
pub fn push(&mut self, value: T) {
    if self.len == self.buf.cap() {
        self.buf.double();
    }
    unsafe {
        let end = self.as_mut_ptr().offset(self.len as isize);
        ptr::write(end, value);
        self.len += 1;
    }
}
```

will attempt to write to memory past the actual end of the memory owned by the container. Because of this critical requirement, modification to `len` is forbidden.

---

**Philosophy**

It's definitely good to use a getter like this in library code (crazy people out there might try to modify it!).

However, one should design their code in a manner that minimizes the requirement of getters/setters. A class should act on its own members as much as possible. These actions should be made available to the public through methods. And here I mean methods that *do useful things* -- not just a plain ol' getter/setter that returns/sets a variable. Setters in particular can be made redundant through the use of constructors or methods. `Vec` shows us some of these "setters":

```
push
insert
pop
reserve
...
```

Thus, `Vec` implements algorithms that provide access to the outside world. But it manages its innards by itself.

Comment: +1 for _usually a better way to improve the design of your program so that getters/setters become unnecessary_. 99% of the time, this is what a constructor does.

Comment: I think one important point that this answer is missing is that exposing the `len` field directly would make `Vec` unsafe (in the memory-safety sense) because there are invariants that need to be preserved in order to not expose uninitialised memory etc.

Comment: @fjh I'd say that *is* the answer and you should add it separately

Comment: *adopt good guidelines and practices. (e.g. don't modify members directly.)* — accessor methods **are** those good practices! One of the points of a statically typed language, especially one like Rust, is to encode as much as you can into the type system so that you don't have to think about "doing the right thing" as much. If we could just mentally encode "good guidelines and practices" we wouldn't even *need* the borrow checker or types because we'd just write the correct thing!

Comment: @Shepmaster I suppose that's my inner Python talking (which has no truly `private` fields). I've removed the contentious bits, though.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq amusingly, I agree with you in certain cases. I usually don't find that I need to protect myself *from myself*, but as soon as there are multiple developers using a piece of code, those walls come in handy. Those multiple developers might just happen to be "past me" and "present me", however.

Answer (score 5):

The  `Vec` struct looks *something like* this<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    capacity: usize,
    len: usize,
}
```

The idea is that `ptr` points at a block of allocated memory of size `capacity`. If the size of the `Vec` needs to be bigger than the `capacity` then new memory is allocated. The unused portion of the allocated memory is uninitialised and could contain arbitrary data.

When you call mutating methods on `Vec` like `push` or `pop`, they carefully manage the `Vec`'s internal state, increase capacity when necessary, and ensure that items that are removed are properly dropped.

If `len` was a public field, any code with an owned `Vec`, or a mutable reference to one, could set `len` to any value. Set it higher than it should be and you'll be able to read from uninitialised memory, causing *Undefined Behaviour*. Set it lower and you'll be effectively removing elements without properly dropping them.

In some other programming languages (e.g. JavaScript) the API for arrays or vectors specifically lets you change the size by setting a `length` property. It's not unreasonable to think that a programmer who is used to that approach could do this accidentally in Rust.

Keeping all the fields private and using a getter method for `len()` allows `Vec` to protect the mutability of its internals, make strong memory guarantees and prevent users from accidentally doing bad things to themselves.

---

<sub>[1] In practice, there are abstraction layers built over this data structure, so it [looks a little different](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#302-305).</sub>

Comment: +1 for the comment that programmers from other languages may assume setting the len changes the vector's size.